# Whitespace collapse logic for browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I am trying to understand the logic for collapsing whitespaces. While I have read the [MDN Docs for the white-space-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space-collapse), I am not able to understand why the browser sometimes trim the leading or trailing whitespaces.

For example, if I look the search bar Github's code explorer [https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/blob/main/apps/www/app/examples/dashboard/page.tsx], the word `Type` has both leading and trailing whitespaces, out of which the leading one is trimmed but the trailing one isn't. On the other hand, for the phrase `to search`, the leading whitespace is not trimmed, while the trailing one is.

[image: Search bar]

[image: HTML]

[image: CSS]

I expected the spaces not to be trimmed. Is there another CSS property which determines this behaviour?